# Undistort single point after calibration

Tags: opencv, calibration

I have question regrading undistortion of a single point using either Scaramuzza or Mei's opencv 
I have done the calibration on a dataset and extracted camera matrix and distortion coefficient (for mei) and the necessary parameters for Scaramuzza, after getting mapx (map1) and mapy (map2) I want to apply the undistortion on a single point.

### for mei:

we have a position for a point (an intersection in a chess board) in a fisheye image, I was able to find its position using findchessboardcoreners (I know this can be used for calibration but I want to know a position for a well-known point in the image), now I have the undistorted image and I want to know the position of that point after the distortion correction,
I have read many links, suggesting to use undistortpoints method, or by using remap method, and I read links describing that dst(x,y)=src(mapx(x,y),mapy(x,y)) and I applied them all but when I draw the resulted point it wasn't on the same intersection of the chessboard it was even out of the board closer to its position in the fisheye

### for Scaramuzza:

I tried to understand world2cam and cam2world methods but still I can't get it right

### so

is there a method to know the position of a single point after the distortion correction if we have its position before the distortion? also can someone explain in deep way mapx and mapy .. I have read examples about them and how they can be used but whenever I wanted to implement the mapping between the distorted point and the undistorted one I got confused, for example: mapx and mapy should have the size of the src (in my case it is a point) so how can I use remap method here? or I should get them form the camera matrix and distortion coefficient and use dst(x,y)=src(map1(x,y),map2(x,y) ?

note
I have applied estimateNewCameraMatrixForUndistortRectify, initUndistortRectifyMap and remap successfully on images (for mei's) and I have also applied the undistortion method which was implemented by Scaramuzza on images with a very satisfying result (better than mei)

Comment: you can apply the distortion formula or take a lookup in the maps for that pixel location

Comment: The maps are given in the opposite direction:  `map1(x,y), map1(x,y)` gives the X, Y coordinate in the source (distorted) image. Assume you are iterating the x,y destination image, and for each pixel you ask: Where is the pixel in the source image to place in x, y? the maps gives you the X, Y in the source image. (X,Y are not integers).

Comment: okay I can see, but if I have a point and its position is (50,60) (just as an example) and I have mapx and mapy and I want to know its new position in the undistorted image, how can I calculate it?

Comment: @Micka, can you please tell me how can I use the lookup tables?

Comment: sorry, since map1 and map2 are giving the reverse direction, you'll have to compute the lookup-matrix manually with the distortion/undistortion formula.

Comment: @Micka, thank you very much, I also read this "Each of the two LUTs (mapx and mapy) represent a two-dimensional matrix LUT_{m,n} where m and n represent the pixel positions of the undistorted image" so if I loop over the mapx and mapy searching for the values equal to the point's position in the distorted image so the returned indices could represent the position in undistiorted image of the point? sorry if I am not getting it right

Comment: I think mapX and mapY are reverse direction, so they are not usable as lookup tables for your task, but you can create two similar matrices for the other direction (from distorted to undistorted image), or you could combine X and Y in a CV_32FC2 matrix.

Comment: @Micka okay thank you very much, I will try to do that

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by undistortpoints openCV function, the problem was I did not use the fisheye::undistortPoints but I was using the original one, still the surrounded points are not in their right position but the result was kind of acceptable